# Using Style Trigger to change string format of a GridView header

Tags: c#, xaml, gridview, triggers, boolean

I am trying to change the format of a header in my gridview based on the contents of a boolean flag.

```
<ListView.Resources>
<Style TargetType="GridViewColumnHeader" x:Key="CountHeaderStyle">
    <Setter Property="ContentStringFormat" Value="{}{0}" />
<Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding HasBase}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="ContentStringFormat" Value="{}{0} (base)" />
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Flag}" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="ContentStringFormat" Value="{}{0}" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

...

```
<GridView>
    <GridViewColumn Header="{Binding ANumber}" HeaderContainerStyle="{StaticResource CountHeaderStyle}">
```

I have verified that when the flag changes, it is being queried (and returning the correct value), but the format of the string in the header doesn't change.  If the value of the flag is initially set to true, the modified string format is used, but subsequent changes to the flag still don't trigger the format to change. Any ideas?